# PHP Syntax ${"field"}

Tags: php, string, variables

I don't recognize the PHP syntax for ${"item_$i"};  item_$i can be item_1 through item_6.  What does the ${  } indicate in the assignment?  I can't find an example in my searches.

```
if($cl_name=='A') $data = ${"item_$i"};
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

It's called [`Complex (curly) syntax`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)

> This isn't called complex because the syntax is complex, but because it allows for the use of complex expressions.
>
> Any scalar variable, array element or object property with a string representation can be included via this syntax. Simply write the expression the same way as it would appear outside the string, and then wrap it in { and }. Since { can not be escaped, this syntax will only be recognized when the $ immediately follows the {. Use {\$ to get a literal {$. Some examples to make it clear:

```
<?php
// Show all errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$great = 'fantastic';

// Won't work, outputs: This is { fantastic}
echo "This is { $great}";

// Works, outputs: This is fantastic
echo "This is {$great}";
echo "This is ${great}";

// Works
echo "This square is {$square->width}00 centimeters broad."; 


// Works, quoted keys only work using the curly brace syntax
echo "This works: {$arr['key']}";


// Works
echo "This works: {$arr[4][3]}";

// This is wrong for the same reason as $foo[bar] is wrong  outside a string.
// In other words, it will still work, but only because PHP first looks for a
// constant named foo; an error of level E_NOTICE (undefined constant) will be
// thrown.
echo "This is wrong: {$arr[foo][3]}"; 

// Works. When using multi-dimensional arrays, always use braces around arrays
// when inside of strings
echo "This works: {$arr['foo'][3]}";

// Works.
echo "This works: " . $arr['foo'][3];

echo "This works too: {$obj->values[3]->name}";

echo "This is the value of the var named $name: {${$name}}";

echo "This is the value of the var named by the return value of getName(): {${getName()}}";

echo "This is the value of the var named by the return value of \$object->getName(): {${$object->getName()}}";

// Won't work, outputs: This is the return value of getName(): {getName()}
echo "This is the return value of getName(): {getName()}";
?>
```